# Can I move objects in real time through XYZ?

Tags: animation

So it sounds really weird but let me explain. I have been getting really into real time animation where the idea is I can grab my armature, lower the framerate so it slows down, and animate it as the timeline plays.

Here is an example someone sent me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlqBWrtDHcM&ab_channel=LandonFerguson

I've got some cool results out of it and I'd like to push it further but I run into the trouble of XY and Z. Where I can only move the armature on 2 planes either X and Z or Y and Z. I can't move it on XYZ. So I am sort of looking to see if anyone else was interested in this and knew of a way to do it.

Personally I thought about plugging in another mouse and trying it that way but I don't think that will work.

Comment: This is one of the only times I can recommend something like this: https://3dconnexion.com/uk/spacemouse/

Comment: well this is interesting. But it says they suspended sales and also I wasn't really looking to spend money on anything yet :'D